# From xml to table using sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, rows

I needed to turn this xml from this:

```
          <Row>
            <Columns>
              <Column>
                <Value>BB1</Value>
                <Name>Location</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>1593338</Value>
                <Name>Location_Key</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Name>Quantity</Name>
              </Column>
            </Columns>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Columns>
              <Column>
                <Value>DR11 40</Value>
                <Name>Location</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>1593251</Value>
                <Name>Location_Key</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Name>Quantity</Name>
              </Column>
            </Columns>
          </Row>
```

To this table with these columns and rows

```
(Location)  (Location_Key)  (Quantity)
BB1         1593338            0 
DR11        1593251            0
```

Using Sql Server

I have been trying for weeks but to no avail.
Any answer would be greatly aprreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Does the table already exist in your database or are you trying to create the table automatically, then add rows to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Row>
            <Columns>
              <Column>
                <Value>BB1</Value>
                <Name>Location</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>1593338</Value>
                <Name>Location_Key</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Name>Quantity</Name>
              </Column>
            </Columns>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Columns>
              <Column>
                <Value>DR11 40</Value>
                <Name>Location</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>1593251</Value>
                <Name>Location_Key</Name>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Name>Quantity</Name>
              </Column>
            </Columns>
          </Row>'

SELECT
    Location = xc.value('(Column[Name="Location"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    LocationKey = xc.value('(Column[Name="Location_Key"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    Quantity = xc.value('(Column[Name="Quantity"]/Value)[1]', 'int')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/Row/Columns') AS XT(XC)
```

This gives you an output something like this:

[image]

You can use this `SELECT` inside an `INSERT INTO .....` or do whatever you like to do with it.

Comment: I also needed to know how/where to declare the namespaces:<br> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <ExecuteDataSourceResponse xmlns="http://www.plexus-online.com/DataSource">`